# Валидация дат на сервере

Tags: c#, mvc, валидация

Есть классы

```
public class MyDateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public object DateToCompare { get; set; }
    public bool IsValueMore { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var e = Convert.ToDateTime(DateToCompare);
        DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        return  (IsValueMore ? d >= e : d <= e); 
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "Admin_Report_StartDate")]
    [ReportSummary(itemOrder: 1, format: ReportColumnFormat.Date)]
    [MyDateValidation(ErrorMessage ="Start date  can't be greater than end date", IsValueMore = false**, DateToCompare = End**]
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "Admin_Report_EndDate")]
    [ReportSummary(itemOrder: 2, format: ReportColumnFormat.Date)]
    [MyDateValidation(ErrorMessage = "Start date  can't be greater than end date", IsValueMore = false, **DateToCompare = Start**))]
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно валидировать End дата больше Start дата для корректной query в сервисе.

Сложность с передачей параметра DateToCompare в класс аттрибута, не знаю как это сделать. Ошибка следующая -

> *object reference is required for the non-static field attribute*.

Прошу совета

Comment: Сложность состоит в сравнении полей самого класса, не константных значений, передаваемых в аттрибут

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16100300/5045688

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Рекомендации помогли